# JavaFX desktop application - socket communication with web serivce

Tags: spring, web-services, sockets, websocket, javafx

I want to develop a simple desktop application with real-time data refresh (on multiple clients). Is it possible to develop an application such as this that communicates with web service over sockets?

Here is what I wish to know:

- What are the basic steps to do this?
- Is it possible to use Spring WebSocket to do this?
- Any code examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can definitely use Spring WebSocket for real-time data refresh on multiple clients. 
Of course, both client and server should support the WebSocket protocol. 
For quick start, take a look at the followed: 
http://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/  
http://start.spring.io/

For full reference of both server and client options take a look here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html 
In particular, it provides a short discussion on when to use it: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-intro-when-to-use

Comment: All examples show comunication between browser and server. Are this examples applicable for comunication between javafx or java swing application ment to run on machine (desktop application). I have little problem of understanding these concepts - comunication between desktop app and REST web service.

Comment: Take a look here http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#websocket-fallback-sockjs-client

Comment: Seems like Spring does not have a pure websocket client. For an example of Java WebSocket client take a look here: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-websocket-client-api.html

Comment: Maybe I can not explain my problem because of language bariere (my english is quite bad) Can I treat my desktop appliction in same way as application I will develop for running in my browser (that allso communicates with server as would my desktop application)

Comment: Don't you have to provide the server side for your desktop app? I.e. you are going to communicate with a server maintained by someone else? But then the server determines the communication protocol with its client... So how can you as a desktop app author can choose the protocol?

Comment: Yes I will use Grails on GlasFish, or Grails on Jetty as my server-side. I will develop server-side app.

Comment: So (1) Spring and Spring WebSocket could help you develop the server side (2) Although Spring is primarily concerned with server apps, you can still use the power of Spring when developing a desktop client app, such as Dependency Injection or RestTemplate for client-side communication with REST server, or SockJsClient for WebSocket communication with the server.

Comment: Welcome, good luck. Just a personal opinion: I would start with a very simple prototype for the server and client communication before doing anything else. This way you'll be able to choose what works for you and what doesn't before you spend much time on development.