# Is it possible to use Java WebSocket with desktop application?

Tags: java, javafx, websocket, responsive

I would like to achieve responsive aplication.

Currently I have java REST service but everytime I want to have fresh data I need to request REST service.

I could have WebSocket Service like that: [image]

I would like to know if it is possible to connect client desktop JavaFX application to WebSocket Service.

Thanks to that I could achieve fullduplex bidirectional communication.

Comment: A web browser is a desktop application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at this post below:

[JavaFX desktop application - socket communication with web serivce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26437995/javafx-desktop-application-socket-communication-with-web-serivce)

You can very well do it by using Spring Websockets api.

You can also take a look at Spring docs below:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html